# When to use a smaller table

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on a database design for an application that will manage Model Congress groups. I'm having particular trouble with the object meant to represent the congress. Right now, the field list looks like this:

```
    | Congress   |
    +------------+
    | congressID |
    | adminID    |
    | speakerID  |
    | hopperID   |
    | floorID    |
    | rulesID    |
    | (etc.)     |
```

This is what each field is meant to represent. Tables/objects are all caps.

- congressID: The primary key (obviously)
- adminID: References the unique `PERSON` who runs the model congress, i.e., the teacher.
- speakerID: References the unique `REP` (representative) who acts as speaker for the congress
- hopperID: References the special `COMMITTEE` (a committee being any place a bill can be sent) to which new bills are initially sent.
- floorID: References the `COMMITTEE` used to represent the congress's floor
- rulesID: References the Rules `COMMITTEE`

As you can see, these fields are important to reference in the context of each model congress. The issue I am having is how to represent the foreign keys, primarily the last four.

It seems I have two choices:

1. Include them all in the Congress table as they are now, or
2. Make smaller tables for each field with composite primary keys, e.g. repID+congressID in Speaker, committeeID+congressID in Hopper, etc.

Is more granular necessarily better? Or does this needlessly complicate things? I've been skirting around my design with the first layout for a while, but whenever I try to draw the ERD from that point, the relationships appear hopelessly mangled.

Comment: Bills can only be sent to one hopper committee?  That doesn't seem realistic.  There's nothing wrong with a table of foreign keys.  However, you're modelling a one to one relationship between a Congress and a speaker, hopper committee, floor committee, and rules committee, respectively.

Comment: The hopper committee serves simply as the place in which new bills are held until they can be introduced to their first proper committee. Throughout the process, bills _must_ be in some committee, be it an actual assembly or a procedural waypoint.

Comment: So do you suggest tables for each special committee and member role?

Comment: The real question is are these FKs truly a 1-1 relationship or is it possible they may be in a one-to-many  or a many to many relationship.

Comment: @HLGEM Is there any doubt? The Congress table has a 1:N relationship with the Committee table, but there can only be one committee of the hopper, floor and rules class per congress.

Answer (score 0):

GROUPS should be a table that can define simply the # of the congress in the name or description (1st, 2nd, etc..) and each PERSON should have an ID, with fields for their names and biographics. Then, an M:N table (call it say, GROUPMEMBERS) with it's own ID, an ID referencing GROUPS and (PERSON or GROUPS - would be two fields so you could attach groups to other groups in a hierarchy). Then, you have a tag table (GROUPROLES) with its own ID, a begin date (and possibly an end date), a reference to GROUPMEMBERS, and a reference to a TYPES table defining one role per row within the membership.

What does this allow you to do? A person's role can now change mid-congress with the dates attached to the roles. Committees can be part of congress (named groups with the # of congress in the description or name), and roles within a committee (like chairman) can be assigned.

Drawbacks? Reporting out involves a bit of gymnastics, but not impossible. The table names aren't directly correlative, but they shouldn't need to be exposed to the application users. Constraints about number of members per role per group would need to be either set up as custom functions in the database, or application-controlled (not recommended).

This also allows you to set up dependent infrastructure that tracks flow of items through committees and you can even report out how many times a single person saw a single thing by their membership to groups the item went through. It can also be used to track votes and denormalize information to large group votes (like passing or dying in committee based on votes) simply by running an aggregate on the vote in question and referencing the group. If this were the case, I'd probably make roles a subclass of a historical table and run everything out of a central history.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but I'm mainly concerned with the markdown of the "special" committees. The hopper, floor, and rules committees have the same attributes as regular committees, but they bear special importance to the congress's procedure. I'm not sure whether to note this with fields in the Congress table or with some other method.

Comment: I fail to see how the proposed structure fails to support that. When you say "special importance" to the procedure of congress, why could this not be handled in a subclass of the roles table, to store extra attributes for certain role types?

Comment: I apologize if my questions seem naive; this is my first database.
In the case of the _members_, it would be a good idea to "store extra attributes for certain role types," as you say; I grant you that. But no additional information is needed about the special _committees_, only that they are unique and significant within the congress. Given that, is it still preferable to make a separate table?

Comment: Yes. You can implement CHECK constraints that will do business-logic testing of data before it updates or inserts new data. Take that as a separate question, though. The application logic can also select these special groups for display in a different way, and the other areas (views) can exclude these special roles from their results.

Also: members is not the place to put such a thing. use the roles table or extend the role table by making a new table (say, hopper) and have its primary key also be a foreign key to the roles table, and then you can easily select its ID from that table.

Comment: I see. My main concern was how to balance brevity and clarity with the need to identify special committees. This solves the problem. Is there some rule of thumb or particular logic that led you to suggest this structure?

Comment: The rule of thumb is that if many groups can contain many People, you're looking at an M:N relationship. M:N relationships need their own table, and are just a set of foreign keys relating groups to members. M:N tables can be handy in thier own right because you not only get to define the groups, members, and who's a part of what, but by referencing your M:N table, you can describe the relationship of the member to the group, even so far as to make it time-sensitive. It looks convoluted to lay persons, but it really does model the type of data we're looking at.